# PyQt4 pushbutton not connecting for my QGIS plugin

Tags: qgis, python, widget, pyqt

I'm trying to display information in a text browser with the push of a button in my QGIS plugin. The .ui is created using PyQt4 (button's object name is calcConso). No error message, but the button isn't connecting. The button simply displays values returned by my stats function, but the function itself isn't actually called anywhere. If it should be, I don't see where yet.

Any ideas what's missing?

```
def initGui(self):
# connect button to calculation function
    QObject.connect(self.dlg.ui.calcConso, SIGNAL("clicked()"), self.buttonClicked)

def buttonClicked(self):
    global stats, values
    self.dlg.clearTextBrowser()
    self.dlg.setTextBrowser( str(stats, values) )

def stats(self):
    global stats, values
    ...
    return stats, values
```

in a separate dialog class i've defined clearTextBrowser() and setTextBrowser(), which is imported.

```
def setTextBrowser(self, output):
    self.ui.txtFeedback.setText(output)

def clearTextBrowser(self):
    self.ui.txtFeedback.clear()
```

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with your connect statement. How do you know it's not connecting? You can test the return value of the ``QObject.connect`` statement to see if it is ``True``. Perhaps your ``setTextBrowser`` method is not doing what you think it should.

Comment: how exactly should i integrate this test into my program? where would I see the results of a print statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To test your connection:

```
from PyQt4.QtGui import QMessageBox
...
result = QObject.connect(self.dlg.ui.calcConso, SIGNAL("clicked()"), self.buttonClicked)
QMessageBox.information(None, 'Connection result', "Connect returned %s" % result)
```